# Find stationary distribution for a continuous time Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Consider the following diagram of the instantaneous transition rates in a continuous time Markov chain. For example, this says $q_{01}=0.5$. Find the stationary distribution $\pi$.

> [image: markov]

**My attempt:**

First I tried to get transition matrix,

$$
P=\pmatrix{
0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0.3 & 0\\
0.6 & 0 & 0 & 0.5\\
0 & 0.6 & 0.3 & 0
}
$$

Then I tried to solve the system,

$$\pi P=\pi, \qquad \sum_{i=0}^3\pi_i=1$$

But it seems the system is not solvable. But the solution said,

> $$\pi \approx \pmatrix{0.20 & 0.53 & 0.17 & 0.10}$$

Now I got doubt that,  **"Does solving $\pi P=\pi, \sum_{i=0}^3\pi_i=1$ is the only way to get the stationary distribution?"**

Comment: Shouldn't the row sums of a continuous time stochastic transition matrix be zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heeding the suggestion of Graf Zahl's comment, we must normalize the rows of the transition matrix in such a way that the row sums are zero, by setting the diagonals equal to the negative of your row sum.
Explicitly, we construct the so-called "generator matrix" derivable from the transition matrix;
$$
P=\pmatrix{
-0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -0.3 & 0.3 & 0\\
0.6 & 0 & -1.1 & 0.5\\
0 & 0.6 & 0.3 & -0.9
}
$$
By doing this, I apply any standard solution method to find $$\pi = (0.20454545, 0.53030303, 0.17045455, 0.09469697)$$ in agreement with your proposed solution.

Comment: Aha, I was introduced with that normalization method, @JacobA. Thanks(+1) for your response. Could you describe how to get limiting distribution of this markov chain? Or which method is standard to get limiting distribution of the markov chain.

Comment: I typically find it convenient to use the power method (wikipedia has a good article on it), or if for some reason you need more info, you can just take the full spectrum with numpy linalg eig for example. Hope it helps!

Comment: Also, be sure to accept the answer if it solves your question (:

Comment: Thanks. Could you redirect me that Wikipedia section? Because googling power method gives me numerical analysis related theorem.

Comment: Yes indeed it may be that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration , it is used in practice to calculate the dominant eigenvector. If you are not confident, just calculate the spectrum by hand!

Comment: Isn't there a method solving by generator matrix, like $\pi G=0$ also give that. I was asking because maybe I read that somewhere but couldn't remember clearly, JacobA

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I've constructed above, let me add an edit. Also see here: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_3_3_the_generator_matrix.php